# Editing Javascript/Source Files for Website in Devtools - not updatign

Tags: javascript, html, angular, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I've got a website running that I'm trying to experiment with in Dev tools. However, when I open up the corresponding ts file from the sources tab, and I make changes and save, those changes aren't reflected. I also tried it with the HTML file, facing the same results.

How do you live edit JS/HTML in Devtools and see those changes live?

Comment: You can't. DevTools doesn't publish to the site.